# SplitView Ipad - Segue to Detail View keeps opening views

Tags: xcode, ipad, split, loadview, detailview

I have an app with a SplitViewController.
On the MasterDetail I have that whenever you push a cell, it performs a push segue to load a new view in the Detail View.

The problem is, if I press the cell 10 times, it opens ten times the detail view and I have to click the Back Button 10 times to go where I started.

How can I solve this??